# Как получить код страницы после её полной загрузки в Powershell

Tags: powershell

Есть цель с помощью Powershell скрипта пропарсить страницу, которая грузится не сразу. Как можно понять с помощью Powershell, когда страница полностью загрузилась? Я гуглил и [нашел 2 варианта](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22510779/can-powershell-wait-until-ie-is-dom-ready):

1. Найти элемент, который присутствует уже на окончательно сформированной странице, и с помощью start-sleep в цикле парсить страницу пока элемент не появится на странице;

   - Не подходит, потому что когда сервис проводит тех работы, элемент, который отображается после полного рендеринга страницы может так и не появится.
2. Использовать InternetExplorer Com-объект и с помощью цикла `while($IE.busy) {Start-Sleep 1}` опять ждать пока страница полностью загрузится.

   - Не очень хочется использовать так как сейчас я буду тестить работу скрипта на windows, но в будущем планирую перенести его на Linux. И хоть на Linux портировали и Powershell и .NET, я не знаю как там будет обстоять работа c COM-объект InternetExplorer.

Comment: "Как получить в Powershell код страницы после её полной загрузки" - так наверно будет более правильная формулировка.

Comment: смысл? некоторые части сайта могут грузиться в ответ на действия пользователя. с этим вы что делать будете?

Comment: @teran , там такого не будет. Это страница статистики. Нужно пропарсить её  для дальнейшего анализа.

Answer (score 0):

тогда зачем реализуешь на Powershell?
с ком объектами скорее всего никак..

Пиши сразу на Python.

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    import requests
    import time
    while True:
        r = requests.get('http://google.com/')
        # для теста строку поиск поменять на Поиск1
        if r.text.find("Поиск")>0:
            break
        time.sleep(5)
        print('пробую еще раз')
    print('нашёл')
```